# How to automatically detect vandalism on traffic signs?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have successfully did stop sign recognition and then I crop the bounding box of the detected stop sign. So my next task is to detect vandalism on the stop sign. For my task, physical damage on the stop sign that change it's shape is not considered as vandalism. The vandalism could be anything that could disturb or block the 'STOP' letters on the sign.

I tried to use opencv function which is cv2.absdiff() to apply background subtraction between the vandalized stop sign image and stop sign template image so that only the differences between these 2 images should appear as the result of the subtraction. However, this subtraction method is a scale and rotation invariant method. It does not work for my task at all.

Right now, I am trying to use color segmentation method. I draw contours on everything besides red colored area and the smallest contour is considered as vandalism. This works for small vandalism but if there was a bigger vandalism that cover most part of the 'STOP' letters, it does not work anymore.

Does anyone knows a better solution to this problem?

Comment: i would try a fine registration/matching of the object image and a template image and use hausdorff-distance on the edge images of the stop letters.